# Is there a way in Matlab using the pseudo number generator to generate numbers within a specific range?

Tags: matlab, random, numbers, integer, range

For example:

```
round(7*rand(1,5))
```

Generates 5 numbers between 1 and 7
Is there a way to generate 5 random numbers between 5 and 7?
Or an abstraction of that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More generally:

```
minInt = 5;
maxInt = 7;
numInts = 10;

r = randi([minInt, maxInt],[1,numInts])

r =

 6     7     7     7     6     5     5     5     7     5
```

Comment: +1 to you @MatlabDoug, for having read the documentation of the RANDI function all the way to the end.

Answer (score 5):

First, if you are wanting to generate random *integer* values, it's better to use the function [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html). Then it's just a matter of shifting and scaling the random numbers accordingly. The following should give you random integers between 5 and 7 inclusive:

```
nums = randi(3,[1 5])+4;
```

**EDIT:** As Amro's comment and [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152334/is-there-a-way-in-matlab-using-the-pseudo-number-generator-to-generate-numbers-wi/2155483#2155483) point out, there is a more straightforward solution whereby you can specify the range directly as the first argument to [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html):

```
nums = randi([5 7],[1 5]);
```

Comment: actually you can specify the desired range directly: `randi([5 7],[1 5])`

Comment: @Amro: Good point. Somehow I skipped over that line in the documentation. ;)