# Using rand in matlab to produce numbers between limits

Tags: matlab, random, limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way in Matlab using the pseudo number generator to generate numbers within a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152334/is-there-a-way-in-matlab-using-the-pseudo-number-generator-to-generate-numbers-wi)

I want to get 20 random integer numbers between -10 and 10 and I thought of using the rand function in matlab.

I thought of myltiplying by ten and then finding a  way to get only the ones between -10 and 10 and use an iteration for each of the other numbers that is outside the limits [-10,10] to get a new number inside the limits.

Is there a better, faster way?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions, but I haven't found one that asked for a range of integers.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
randomIntegers = randi([-10,10],[20,1])
```

to generate a vector of random integers between -10 and 10.

Comment: thanks! My code was 12 lines and now it just needs one!

Comment: +1, Since people on this site aren't in the habit of upvoting correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

Although Jonas' solution is really nice, `randi` isn't in some of the early versions of MATLAB. I believe all versions have `rand`. A solution using `rand` would be:

```
randomIntergers = floor(a + (b-a+1) .* rand(20,1));
```

where [a,b] is the range of values you want a distribution over.

If you are use `round(a + (b-a))` you will have a nonuniform effect on the values of 'a' and 'b'. This can be confirmed using the `hist()` function. This is because the domain that maps into 'a' and 'b' is half the size for all other members of the range.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't use this answer.  It's not uniform.  Try `a = -10; b = 10; x =  round(a + (b-a) .* rand(20000,1)); hist(x,1000);`  The -10 and 10 case are less likely than the others.

Comment: This fixes it.  `x =  floor(a + (b-a+1) .* rand(20,1));`

Comment: hmm, I always thought 'floor(A)' rounded to the nearest integer less than or equal to A, so 'floor(-.9) = -1' but 'floor(.9) = 0'. Whereas round just goes to the nearest integer. It seems intuitively to me that floor will bias data to the left, giving you a new mean around -0.5.

Comment: I suggest computing it and then looking at the `hist(x,1000)` of it then convincing yourself why it works.

Comment: wow, I never took the time to look at the histogram when creating random numbers. There is a nonuniform distribution at the edge numbers using round. This makes sense because the domain that maps into -10 and 10 is half the size for all other members of the range. There still is a problem using floor though, as no members of the range will map into the integer 10. (-10 also gets excluded if you try to use `ceil`). Guess the best way is to pick all positive values with a mean above zero, create a random distribution, then subtract the mean to get a zero mean, uniform distribution.

Comment: you didn't catch the `(b-a+1)` instead of `(b-a)` in my comment did you?