# Implement 'randi' using 'rand' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

To increase backward compatibility i want to replace all my "randi([m,n])" to some function that uses only rand, as people with earlier versions of MATLAB do not have randi function.

Comment: Use [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) to check for the existence of the RANDI function first so that you don't overload it for users running modern MATLAB versions.

Comment: @b3: I would use EXIST instead of WHICH: `exist('randi','builtin')==5`

Comment: BTW, this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415424/using-rand-in-matlab-to-produce-numbers-between-limits/6415698#6415698

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about `randi(imax,[m,n])`, you could use something like:

```
ceil(imax*rand([m,n]))
```

If you mean `randi([imin,imax])`, refer to the link Amro provided in the comments: [Using rand in matlab to produce numbers between limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415424/using-rand-in-matlab-to-produce-numbers-between-limits/6415698#6415698)

Comment: To be exact, `randi([m,n])` means generate a number in the interval [m,n], which is not the same as `rand([m,n])` which generates a matrix of size m-by-n of uniform numbers