# Function to find entries with same maximum value in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-compiler

In my project I need a function which returns the index of the largest element of a given vector. Just like `max`. For more than one entry with the same maximum value (which occurs frequently) the function should choose one randomly. Unlike `max`.

The function is a subfunction in a MATLAB Function Block in Simulink. And the whole Simulink model is compiled.

My basic idea was:

```
function ind = findOpt(vector)
index_max = find(vector == max(vector));
random = randi([1,length(index_max)],1);
ind = index_max(random);
end
```

But I got problems with the comparison in `find` and with `randi`.
I found out about safe comparison here: [Problem using the find function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669942/problem-using-the-find-function-in-matlab). Also I found a way to replace `randi([1,imax],1)`: [Implement 'randi' using 'rand' in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113284/implement-randi-using-rand-in-matlab).

My Code now looks like this:

```
function ind = findOpt(vector)
tolerance = 0.00001;
index_max = find(abs(vector - max(vector)) < tolerance);
random = ceil(length(index_max)*rand(1));
ind = index_max(random);
end
```

Still doesn't work. I understand that the length of index_max is unclear and causes problems. But I can not think of any way to know it before. Any ideas how to solve this?

Also, I'm shocked that `ceil` doesn't work when the code gets executed?? In debug mode there is no change to the input visible.

I thought about creating an array like: `index_max = abs(vector - max(vector)) < tolerance;` But not sure how that could help. Also, it doesn't solve my problem with the random selection.
Hopefully somebody has more ideas or at least could give me some hints!

I am using MATLAB R2012b (32bit) on a Windows7-64bit PC, with the Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 compiler.

**Edit:**
Vector usually is of size 5x1 and contains values between -2000 and zero which are of type double, e.g. `vector = [-1000 -1200 -1000 -1100 -1550]'`. But I think such a simple function should work with any kind of input vector.

The call of `length(index_max)` causes an system error in MATLAB and forces me to shut it down. I guess this is due to the strange return I get from `find`. For a vector with all the same values the return from `find` is something like `[1.000 2.000 1.000 2.000 0.000]'` which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: what does not work? Tried your code in matlab and it seems fine?

Comment: In MATLAB it works fine for me, too. But running the Simulink model causes an runtime error, saying: "Expected an integer value, found non-integer variable random with value 4.07362." For the line with: ind=index_max(random);

Comment: hmm. That is interesting..

Comment: implement ceil yourself.

Comment: could you post your vector? I guess there are lot of simple solutions using `find` and `randi`, but I guess you don't want to use them

Comment: Put `random = length(index_max)*rand(1)` and `random = ceil(random)` on consecutive lines, without a semicolon. What is the output from those two lines? Also put `which ceil` in the function, after the line calling ceil, and give us the output of that line too.

Comment: Putting `which ceil` gives me an coder error, stating: "Function 'which' is not supported for coed generation. [...]". And `ceil(x)` still returns x.

Comment: If you open a fresh MATLAB and call `findOpt(rand(100, 1))`, does it work? If so, I guess that the code from which you normally call `findOpt()` is overloading `ceil()`; you need to find where.

Comment: I stored `findOpt()` in a M-file and did like you said. Works perfectly fine, even for my original implementation. But still, in a MATLAB function block in Simulink it won't work. Don't think I'm overloading `ceil`. Could it be an issue with the compiler? Tomorrow I'll get the chance to try it on a different PC. Let's see what happens there ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function v= findOpt(v)
if isempty(v)
    return;
end
v = find((max(v) - v) < 0.00001);
v = v(ceil(rand(1)*end));
end
```

Comment: Tried it, but still get an runtime error for "ceil(rand(1)*end)" Somehow ceil doesn't do what it should do and just passes through "rand(1)*end".

Comment: What's the output of `which ceil`? Mine is `built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\matlab\elfun\@double\ceil)  % double method`.

Comment: `built-in (C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\matlab\elfun\@double\ceil)  % double method`

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed overloading, just like user664303 suggested! Since I can not use objects in my project, I wanted an function that behaves similar, so I wrote:

```
function varargout = table(mode, varargin)
persistent table;

if isempty(table) && ~strcmp(mode,'writeTable')
     error(...)
end

switch mode
     case 'getValue'
        ...
     case 'writeTable'
        table = ...
     ...
end
end
```

Wanted to avoid passing the dimensions for the table in every call and thought it would be enough if the first call initializes the Table with `mode='writeTable'`. Looks like this caused my problem.
No problems after changing to:

```
if isempty(table)
     table = zeros(dim1,dim2,...)
end
```