# Generate nonnegative random number ( matlab)

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a N dimensional column vector in matlab, with mean 0.5 ( variance is ok to adjust ) , but I want all numbers to be positive, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: positive or nonnegative?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806158/generate-a-random-number-with-max-min-and-mean-average-in-matlab

Comment: Do you care about the distribution of the numbers?

Comment: I just noticed "N dimensional column vector". A column vector is by definition one domensional. Did you mean "with N elements"? If so `rand(N,1)` might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the distribution that you want. The `rand(v)` function generates a uniform random distribution (range `[0,1]` I believe although I'm not sure if either 0 or 1 are theoretically possible values) in an array with dimensions `v`.

So if you want a `3x4x5x6` array, you would do

```
myRandArray = rand([3 4 5 6]);
```

If you want the upper value to be larger, you could do

```
myRandArray = maxVal * rand([3 4 5 6]);
```

Where `maxVal` is the largest value. And if you want a range `minVal` to `maxVal`, then do

```
myRandArray = minVal + (maxVal - minVal) * rand([3 4 5 6]);
```

For other distributions (like `randn` for normal distribution) you can make adjustments to the above, obviously.  If you want a "truncated normal distribution" - you may need to start with too many values:

```
dims = [3 4 5 6];
n = prod( dims );
tooMany = 0.5 + randn(2 * n); % since you want mean = 0.5
tooMany(tooMany < 0) = [];
if numel( tooMany ) > n
  myRandArray = reshape(tooMany(1:n), dims);
end
```

You can obviously improve on this, but it's a general idea.

For example, you could generate only `n` values, see how many fail (say m), then generate another m * n / (n - m), and repeat as needed until you have exactly n.

Note that the mean of the final distribution is no longer `0.5` since we cut off the tail. A 'normal distribution' cannot remain 'normal' if you exclude certain values. But then you didn't specify what distribution you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

E.g. create a vector of 1000 random values drawn from a normal distribution with a mean of 0.5 and a standard deviation of 5.

```
a = 5;
b = 0.5;
y = a.*randn(1000,1) + b;
```

To make it positive, then you can delete all the numbers that are negative or zero and generate some more until you got n positive numbers.

Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/numbers-from-normal-distribution-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html) for more info.

Comment: Taking the `abs` makes this very much not a random distribution any more. Of course, neither does removing negative values… but I think the latter is less "damaging" to the part of the distribution that is > 0

Comment: @Floris Year, `abs` is a bad choice. Updated. Thanks.