# Programming an lcg in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I'm trying to solve the questions below in Matlab using a linear congruential generator. My line of code for the function is shown below. `m` is basically the maximum value of the range of values you can expect and so depends on the question. The initial seed `x` is determined first by the clock and then each random number is fed back into the function to produce a new one. The rules for picking lcg values are given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator. What I need is good values for `a` and `c` for the designated period.

My lcg code

```
random_number = mod((a*x + c),m);
```

- Q1 requires a random number between 1 and 52 (probability of poker hands)
- Q2 requires a random number between 1 and 366 (birthday paradox)
- Q3 requires a random number between 1 and 3 (Monty Hall Problem)
- Q4 requires numbers between 1 and 1000

I know it may seem pretty simple but implementing this with small ranges tends to produce a pattern with a small period i.e. 4 digits repeating continually.

Also it may be possible to use a different `m` value and filter out any values outside my required range but honestly I don't think that should be necessary.
Thanks very much

Comment: LCG's seem to prone to periodicity, especially with a small value of m. You could use a larger value of m and scale the output appropriately. (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415424/ - see second answer + comments)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a little bit differently:

- Take some of the *known* values (wikipedia has a table)
- if you take them, you could *assume** they have uniform distribution
- scale the results to your range, e.g. `rnd()*52 / m  + 1` and take that as an output

  *just keep in mind, "when you assume, you make ass out of U and Me" ;)