# create random array in matlab with range of integer

Tags: matlab

I want to create a random array with values between 0 to 255 but without any looping value, like (0: 255) but its value is scrambled. how to do it?

output like

```
32, 204, 16, 92, ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in Matlab using the pseudo number generator to generate numbers within a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152334/is-there-a-way-in-matlab-using-the-pseudo-number-generator-to-generate-numbers-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With really random and possibly repeating numbers:

```
randi(256,1,256)-1
```

Every value occuring exactly once, random permutation:

```
randperm(256)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the randperm function.

```
result = randperm(255);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by looping but if you want a random array with values between 0 and 255 uniformly distributed you can do this:

```
a = floor(256*rand(1,10000));
```

This will give you an array with 10000 values uniformly distributed between 0 and 255